# jQuery auto refresh div malfunctioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, refresh

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Basically I'm after loading content (an image) into a div tag, and then refreshing it every x seconds. So this is what I came up with, and it works great until it fades the file back in to which it does a manual refresh.

The current process looks like the following:

Load ... fade out, fade in & then disappears and reappears a few seconds later.

What should be happening is the following:

Load ... fade out, fade in ... fade out, fade in ... (you get the idea, looped)

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#webcam").load("image.html").fadeIn("slow");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#webcam_img").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#webcam").load('image.html');
      $("#webcam_img").fadeIn("slow");
   }, 5000);
});
```

The online file can be found here: http://colourednoise.co.uk/scripts/webcam.htm

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`load` is asynchronous.  You are calling `fadeIn` on an element which is then replaced by the `load`.  You need to `fadeIn` within the callback of `load` to ensure that the element exists.

```
$("#webcam").load('image.html', function(){
    $("#webcam_img").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: After looking at it again, the answer really is a combination of my answer and @wirey's.  You are potentially replacing the image before it has faded out (and noted by wirey) and fading in before the element is loaded.

Comment: Ah man, I hate to be a pain, but one last quick question, is it possible for this to work with updating images? Basically it's for a webcam page and the webcam is shown by images uploaded on a 5 second basis.

Comment: If the image `id` doesn't change, I see no reason why this wouldn't work as-is.

Comment: the file just gets re-uploaded (in the same file name), however right now it's just going round and round on a carousel with the same images

http://colourednoise.co.uk/scripts  it's stumped me too, I don't know how it's not working

Comment: My guess would be that it's caching the request somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 3):

Try moving your fadein inside the callback function for the fadeOut so it waits until fadeout is complete first

```
   $("#webcam_img").fadeOut("slow",function(){
      $("#webcam").load('image.html');
      $("#webcam_img").fadeIn("slow");   
   });
```

Here's the full example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#webcam").load("image.html").fadeIn("slow");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#webcam_img").fadeOut("slow",function(){ // <-- added callback function
         $("#webcam").load('image.html'); // now this
         $("#webcam_img").fadeIn("slow"); // and this waits for fadeOut to complete first  
      });
   }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: To do that I would have to remove ar refreshId = setInterval(function() { wouldn't I? Thus stopping the 'autoness' of refreshing itself

Comment: @JamesLawson no you don't.. I just updated my answer to show you how it would look like

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different way to do it, ensuring that each image is fully loaded before the next refresh gets queued:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#webcam").load("image.html").fadeIn("slow", function () { setTimeout(refreshImage, 5000) });

    function refreshImage() {
        $("#webcam_img").fadeOut("slow",function(){
            $("#webcam").load('image.html');
            $("#webcam_img").fadeIn("slow", function() { setTimeout(appendDateToBody, 5000) });
        });
    }
});
```